are questions about neurodiversity/behavior issues acceptable here?
I was scrolling through area 51 looking for interesting communities i could help out and i came across a neurodiversity stack exchange in the defining stage and im wondering how it is different from here. It might be a more focused one but we dont need that do we? this seems to need as many things to focus on as it can get as its question rate is low at the moment. So im just looking for clarification that these sites are different from eachother and neither will steal focus from the other.

Thank you for bringing this proposal to our attention!
There is some overlap with the neurodiversity proposal, but also some clear differences.

Proposed Q&A site for the people looking to know more about neurodiversity (autism, ADH-D, dys- spectrum, OCD ...) and for neurodiverse people looking for some advice on how to deal with neurotypical-based situations.

Questions on the former part of this description are likely to be on topic here, but the latter ("and for neurodiverse people looking for some advice on how to deal with neurotypical-based situations.") is off-topic here due to our 'self-help' guideline.
For example, looking at the list of example questions on the proposal:

"Is there a proved connection between autism and tiredness?" could be on topic, in case it includes sufficient initial research.
but the most up voted one at the time of writing, "I have issues with sensory overload due to noise. How can I alleviate that in a public setting like a party?", would be closed here.

